# No "Guided Breathing" Activity Type available through Google Fit SDK

Tags: android, google-fit

I would like to add a "Guided breathing" activity type, supported by the REST Api under id 122:

https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types

However, it is not available in the FitnessActivites class, despite the fact that most (all?) other are:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessActivities

Is there a way to add this particular activity type through the Google Fit SDK? I know I can just set a different name with a Session.Builder.setName method, but that wouldn't be sufficiently localised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be available in the next SDK release.

Activity types are just `String` literals, so I believe you could just use "guided_breathing" in the interim.